# Run a PHP file from another file

Tags: php

I have a script on my server send sends email. and shows a response as 0 or 1

### Here is the URL :

```
 http://examplewebsite.com/emailsender.php?to=$to&subject=$subject&message=$message
```

I am punting data in $to,$messages,$header.And it's sending the email.

I need to get the response of the page too.

How can i do that?

Comment: PHP has a mail() function, why use an external service?

Comment: I assume he has a central page for sending mail which includes the mail() function

Comment: Right now anyone can send mail from that server - I just tested it. Update your question to use an example url and then add security to your service

Comment: Oooh, a web-service I could use to send SPAM!

Answer (score 3):

use file_get_contents or curl to get the output:

```
$output = file_get_contents(" http://smwebtech.com/webservices/emailsender.php?to=$to&subject=$subject&message=$message");
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL can be called with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), both will give you the resulting HTML.

You should implement some sort of security to prevent people abusing your email script, such as an IP whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there are a number of ways. The easiest is file_get_contents() (which supports URL wrappers), or if you want a bit more power but more setup you can use CURL.

```
<?php
  $response = file_get_contents('http://smwebtech.com/webservices/emailsender.php?to=$to&subject=$subject&message=$message');
  var_dump($response);
?>
```